# Do I need Thread Synchronization, when reading from a shared resource? (C)

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, shared

Let's imagine I have a global array in my program, so all threads created can access it. Or let's imagine I pass it as an argument to every thread (same thing, because it's the reference to the array, so every thread will be accessing the very same array).

My question is:

If I create this array in the beggining of the program (when no threads have been created), and send it to every thread, where they'll only need to read from it, do I need Thread Synchronization?

I know there would be a problem with writing on the array, but no thread ever writes in the array. They only read it. It's like a constant.

Comment: The answer is "no". What kind of issues do you expect there?

Comment: In case you are worried about potential visibility issues, see [cppreference on thrd_create](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thrd_create): "The completion of this function synchronizes-with the beginning of the thread." This should be enough to guarantee visibility for the use case you describe here. Disclaimer: of course, cppreference is not an authoritative source, so if you need to be sure, check the parts of the standard that they refer to.

Answer (score 0):

if you read the global array you can access it from more thread at the same time and you don't need any kind of synchronization, this is the kind of event which you need to use the parallelism of architecture.

Comment: You might want to note that is applies exclusively to every thread only ever reading from a constant array, the term "access" is ambiguous. Also, parallelism isn't required for having multiple threads, they just can't run at the same time. Even with non-multiprocessing threading, you can have issues with non-atomic modificaitons to a shared resource.